# DDD: inter-domain referencing design issue?

Tags: domain-driven-design

What are DDD recommendations for inter-domain referencing design?

Should I try to connect them as "Matryoshka" (put one into another) or it is better to create upper-level "inter-domain" business service?

P.S. Crossing this smooth water, I was unable to find anything useful to read in the Internet, and have started thinking that for this kind of things exist better term than "inter-domain referencing"... Am I right?

DETAILS:

1. I have two models/business services.
2. Semantically first domain (A) is CRM with sell/maintenance process for our goods, second domain (B) is "design" data of our goods. We have two view points on our goods: from seller perspective and from engineer perspective.
3. Actually each model is effective ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) tool to the same database.
4. There are some inter-domain activities e.g. validations (e.g. sometimes we can sell things to smb. only if  some engineering rules are valid).

From developer's point of view I have two clear possibilities (reference B in A or create new cross reference domain/service C ). But from designer perspective I am lost in understanding what kind of Business Service I have when I compose business logic from two different domains.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your support. I've added some details to the question, when example of inter-domain communication could be: validate order, that means validate goods compatibility at "order creation time", by the rules that are stored in the "remote" domain.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, DDD has no strict rules for 'inter-domain' referencing. At the end of the day your domain model will have to reference basic Java or .NET classes. Or it may reference specialized date/time or graph library (aka 'Generic Domain').

On the other hand DDD has a concept of [Bounded Context](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/91). And it has quite a few patterns that can be applied when you work at the boundaries of the system. For example 'Anticorruption Layer' can be used to isolate you from legacy system. Other integration styles can be used depending on how much control you have over external code, team capabilities etc.

So there is probably no need to introduce artificial glue layer if you just dealing with two subdomains in one Bounded Context. Might also be worth reading Part 4 of [DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)  (Strategic Design).

UPDATE:

Based on the information you provided, it looks like you only have one Bounded Context. You don't seem to have 'linguistic clashes' where the same word have two different meanings. Bounded Context integration patterns are most likely not applicable to your situation. Your Sales domain can reference Products domain directly. If you think of Products domain being more low-level and Sales being high level you can use [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf). Define an interface like `ProductCompatiblityValidator` in Sales and implement it in Products domain. And then inject the actual implementation at the application layer. This way you will not have a direct reference from Sales to Products.

Comment: Thank you for your support. What are other integration styles? I have full control over external code.

Comment: Am I right to understand that Bounded Context is the way to deal with two different models of the one domain and generally is not purposed to glue two different domains?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Dmitry has already said...

I think of any code that crosses bounded contexts as *application layer* code. I would have that application layer code reference domain types from both contexts (and their repositories) but not have two domains reference each other. I think it's OK to have business logic in an application layer if it specifically crosses domain boundaries and is unit-testable.

If you really have a hierarchy, then it would be OK to have the the more concrete subdomain reference the more abstract domain. However, I would be careful if this causes you to need to have domain objects reference repositories of any type. Pulling objects out of of a *repository* is rarely a true domain concept. Referencing repositories is best done in an application layer that sits a layer above the domain model.

Of course this is all as much art as science. I'd try modeling a thin slice of your application a couple different ways and see what friction you run into with each approach.